# Parallel computation with joblib in Flask

Tags: python, flask, parallel-processing, joblib

I have a `python` function that I need to call repeatedly with different argument values. I would like to execute this in parallel across multiple CPUs. I have done this successfully using the `joblib` module. I would now like to make my code available as a web app using `flask` running on an `AWS EC2 instance` with multiple CPUs. Here is a toy example of what I have tried:

```
from flask import Flask
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
from time import sleep

def myfunc(x):
    sleep(5)
    return x

application = Flask(__name__)

@application.route('/', methods = ['GET'])
def getresult():
    out = Parallel(n_jobs=-1, verbose=10)(delayed(myfunc)(i) for i in range(5))
    return str(sum(out))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.debug = True
    application.run()
```

The problem is that this code ***does not run in parallel*** across multiple CPUs. I get the following warning and output (the elapsed times confirm that it is not running in parallel):

```
    /Library/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py:547:
    UserWarning: Multiprocessing-backed parallel loops cannot be nested below 
    threads, setting n_jobs=1
      **self._backend_args)
    [Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Done   1 out of   1 | elapsed:    5.0s remaining:    0.0s
    [Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Done   2 out of   2 | elapsed:   10.0s remaining:    0.0s
    [Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Done   3 out of   3 | elapsed:   15.0s remaining:    0.0s
    [Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Done   4 out of   4 | elapsed:   20.0s remaining:    0.0s
    [Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Done   5 out of   5 | elapsed:   25.0s remaining:    0.0s
    [Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Done   5 out of   5 | elapsed:   25.0s finished
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Look at the UserWarning you get there:

```
UserWarning: Multiprocessing-backed parallel loops cannot be nested below 
threads, setting n_jobs=1
```

Maybe this helps:

[Multiprocessing backed parallel loops cannot be nested below threads, setting n_jobs=1](https://github.com/joblib/joblib/issues/180)

Flask is probably spinning up it's own threads under the hood, 
so your getresult() might not run in MainThread.

Comment: Admittedly, I am not an expert in parallel processing so I don't fully understand the warning. But I did try setting `threading.current_thread().name == 'MainThread'` as suggested in the post you referenced, and it didn't help.

Comment: actually it would have to be: 
`threading.current_thread().name = 'MainThread'`

as it seems joblib is checking if the name is 'MainThread'...

Comment: Yes, you're right - but it still doesn't solve the problem unfortunately.

Comment: Any updates on this? It cannot be that you can't run parallel processes from a flask route